# Image gradient of $x$-axis

Tags: image-processing, gradient

I am trying to find gradient of the following image. Now shouldn't the gradient for $x$ be the vertical lines with respect to axes we have on the top left corner please?

[image]

Comment: They adopted a convention where $y$ increases left to right and $x$ increases top to bottom so the images are labeled properly. It's not a typical convention,but they have specified it, so there isno issue.

Comment: @lightxbulb. So you mean when taking the derivative, $x$ is the horizontal one while $y$ is the vertical one? What about the convention please? I did not get it?

Comment: If you had an imaginary cursor and you moved it top to bottom its $x$ coordinate would increase due to the $x$ basis vector pointing down. In the exact same way if you were to move that same cursor from left to right then its $y$ coordinate would increase.

Comment: @lightxbulb. Thank you. But when taking the derivative, we treat $x$ as horizontal while $y$ is vertical?

Comment: $x$ is the vertical axis (increasing top to bottom) as indicated by the basis vector in the top right, while $y$ is the horizontal one (increasing left to right).

Comment: @lightxbulb. Thanks. But if that is the case, why the derivative  of $x$ in the image above are the horizontal red lines?

Comment: Idk what the point of the red lines is tbh, it's just scribbles on top of the derivative images as far as I can tell. In practice you would compute those images using finite differences. For example if your image is `float img[w][h];` then the $x$ derivative image may be computed as `dx[x][y] = img[x][y] - img[x-1][y]` with special boundary handling amounting to `img[-1][y] = img[0][y]`. A similar approach with differences along the second index would yield the approximation of the $y$ derivative.